# Grails - Rendering page after ajax call in JS method

Tags: ajax, grails

Try to make a call to a method in my controller that will essentially render the page I am on so that updates are displayed. What do I need to add to my ajax call to call the grails method?

My desired flow is:

- On view roster
- Select check boxes, hit actionSubmit, onclick go to JS function that has an ajax call to a method in my controller.
- The call at my controller, updateInformation, will update all selected people
- After the call, I want to update my view roster. (currently the flow
  ends after JS call)

roster.gsp:

```
$.ajax({ 
url: "updateInformation", 
type:"GET",
data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList), option:option, id:id}
});
```

I want to call in Controller:

```
def roster() {
   [render stuff]
}

def updateInformation() {
    ... stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grails resolve the mapping by url path by default, so the follow should get the your controller.action once you replace it to your controller and action name:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/$controller/$action", 
    type:"GET",
    data:{ids:JSON.stringify(idList), option:option, id:id}
});
```

Also, if you are using grails2 below, your controller action should be a closure:

```
def viewPage = {
    //
}
```

If you don't want to change the call, the original example will be calling the `updateNumbers` controller default action.
If you want to map the original call to `updateNumbers.viewPage`, you can set the default action to `viewPage` like this `static defaultAction = "viewPage"` in you `updateNumbers` controller.